# Adjust Rear Derailleur

Tags: maintenance, derailleur-rear

10 speed Ultegra CS 6600.

When I march up and down the gears on the stand it shifts fine. If I test it on the road and march up down the gears it shifts fine. But on a ride if I have been coasting for a while and then pedal about 1 in 5 times it will jump a gear and then jump back (not a function of how hard I pedal - more random).

Chain, cassettes, and chain ring are all OK - not new but not worn out. Bike is 10 years old but it has new wheels and plan to keep riding it.

My thought is to replace the cables. What should I try before I take it to the bike shop?

Comment: Is your freehub in good condition?

Comment: @Batman Freehub seems fine to me.  What should I check?  There is like 2-3mm of play up down on the cassette.

Comment: 2-3mm of play seems like a lot to me...

Comment: I will pull the cassette, have a look, and report.

Comment: Just a thought, do you have the spacer on behind the cassette? Without it you'd end up with play and dodgy shifting.

Comment: The cassette was not tight. I was able to unscrew it by hand. I pulled it a fee weeks ago must have not tightened it.  I will not be able to go for a long ride until the weekend to test it out.  Batman or trengot please submit that as an answer.

Comment: Neil Fein it is derailleur in the tags and the M-Webster dictionary.

Comment: Down voter care to comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked Batman or Trengot to post an answer but they had not.

I tightened the cassette and it was better but not perfect.

So I put a new chain on it and not better.

Next new cables and it did need new cables but it was not perfect.

Finally I noticed the cassette was loose again.  I pull out the torque wrench and torqued it to spec - 45Nm. I was just not torquing it down enough.  Now it is perfect.

Comment: Do you have the tools to tight it well? If you didn't tight it 2 times, it seems like you missing something.

Comment: @Alexander  A torque wrench is not the right tool?

Comment: @Alexander None of those is a torque wrench.  A torque wrench is the correct tool to achieve 45 Nm and as stated in my answer fixed the problem.

Comment: @Alexander The new link is not valid.  A torque wrench is the correct tool to achieve a specific torque.  As stated in the question and comment - that fixed the problem.

Comment: Ok. Never mind.